# openxlsx deleteRows corrupting file

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

Im reading in a template file, delete rows and then saving the file again but when I try to open up the file excel says it is corrupted.

Here is my code:

```
template <- loadWorkbook('foo.xlsx')
deleteData(template,sheet=1,cols=1:10000, rows = 6:10005 gridExpand = FALSE)
saveworkbook(template,'foo-test.xlsx',overwrite = TRUE
```

I have even tried it without the deleteData line and it still corupt the file.

Anyone have ideas son how I can change my code/ not corrupt the file.

Comment: Don't know for sure without a reproducible question. It might be best to submit this as a [new issue](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/new/choose) on the maintainer's github repo.

Comment: Hmm, your code runs fine on my machine with arbitrary excel files (after fixing some commas and brackets). Are you sure your foo.xlsx is not corrupted already? 

template <- loadWorkbook('test.xlsx')
deleteData(template,sheet="Sheet 1",cols=1:10000, rows = 6:10005, gridExpand = FALSE)
saveWorkbook(template,'foo-test.xlsx',overwrite = TRUE)